# Struct methods: Cannot borrow as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have the following code (just an example) which can't satisfy the borrow checker.
One method modifies one field of the `struct` and calls another method to modify the other. The problem is when calling the second method it needs a parameter that depends on the struct. The call to `second` method doesn't work with argument `&self.a` and neither `&mut self.a` because that would be a second mutable borrow.

In the end I fixed it by having all the code in just one method, but that's ugly as hell (in my real problem).
How can this be solved? (I know the parameter `&self.a` is not required, but that's not the point I want to illustrate...)

```rust
struct ABC {
    a: Vec<i32>,    // no Copy trait
    b: i32,
}

impl ABC {
    fn new() -> ABC { ABC {a: vec![0,1], b: 10} }

    fn first(&mut self) {
        self.a.push(2);         // updates one field
        self.second(&self.a);   // uses a method to update the other field
    }

    fn second(&mut self, x: &Vec<i32>) {
        self.b += x[1];
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = ABC::new();
    s.first();
}
```

[Playground here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b0b4e93f54aba4ec47b2c62f78819336).

Comment: You can make it a helper function `fn second(y: &mut i32, x: &Vec<i32>)` if you just want that part to be encapsulated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already borrowed from self.a; so as long as that borrow is there, you cannot move out to a second method. You can use `to_vec()` to copy the data to the second method.

```
struct ABC {
    a: Vec<i32>,    // no Copy trait
    b: i32,
}

impl ABC {
    fn new() -> ABC { ABC {a: vec![0,1], b: 10} }

    fn first(&mut self) {
        self.a.push(2);         // updates one field
        self.second(self.a.to_vec());
    }

    fn second(&mut self, x: Vec<i32>) {
        self.b += x[1];
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = ABC::new();
    s.first();
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b0b4e93f54aba4ec47b2c62f78819336)

But as indicated, it will copy the data.

The simplest would be to update `self.b` in `first` method. In that way we don't borrow twice from `self.a`

```
    fn first(&mut self) {
        self.a.push(2);         // updates one field
        self.b += self.a[1];
    }
```

If second does not borrow from `self`, it will work as follow:

```
struct ABC {
    a: Vec<i32>, // no Copy trait
    b: i32,
}

impl ABC {
    fn new() -> ABC {
        ABC {
            a: vec![0, 1],
            b: 10,
        }
    }

    fn first(&mut self) {
        self.a.push(2); // updates one field
        Self::second(&mut self.b, &self.a);
    }
    fn second(y: &mut i32, x: &Vec<i32>) {
        *y += x[1];
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = ABC::new();
    s.first();
}
```

But it is not much different from updating `self.b` directly in `first` method.

Comment: but `to_vec()` makes a clone and is inefficient for large vectors. I just want a reference in order to read some values from the vector without mutating them.

Comment: In that case why not update the vector in `first` method ?

Comment: You don't have to remove `second` from the `impl ABC` block to make it work without a `self` argument; you just have to call it like `Self::second(...)`. (If `second` is only used inside `first`, I would seriously consider putting it *inside* `first` to limit its scope, but perhaps that partially defeats the purpose of factoring it out in the first place.)

Comment: @trentcl Yes, I ended up moving `second` inside `first` as said in the question, but just wanted to know how to solve that problem anyway. The `Self::second(...)` does it, thanks. I will accept this updated answer. Thanks @edkeveked.